# Pyparsing equivalent to the quotedString Regex type without the quotes?

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I am trying to implement a (optional) nested function grammar with pyparsing. Using a simple syntax like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331004/how-to-parse-nested-function-calls-using-pyparsing), I had this up and running in no time.

My grammar is defined like this:

```
fnc = pp.Forward()
arg = pp.quotedString | pp.Word(pp.alphanums) | fnc #  + ' []:=&!*#$/+'
fnc << pp.Group(pp.Word('!$#&') + pp.Word(pp.alphanums) + pp.Literal('(') + pp.Optional(pp.delimitedList(arg)) + pp.Literal(')'))
```

So, from what I've gathered with my testing, `quotedString` can match absolutely any kind of text without any problem and whitespace is also handled properly. The `fnc` parser above can handle almost anything. For example `"&foo(arg1, arg2)"` (which points to `pp.Word(pp.alphanums)`) or `"&foo('$Test,*Option1', &foo(arg2))"` (the first arg points to `quotedString`. Here the extra symbols `"$,*"` are handled by quotedString I believe, although I have not explicitly defined them somewhere. The second arg points to `fnc`).

My problem arises when I write something that is not in quotes. For example, consider a function with keyword arguments: `&foo(1,2.5,3.635, mode='multiply', decimals=3)`. This already throws an exception that it is `expecting ")" (at char 8)`, because the dot is not defined in the `arg` above. (If I put each argument in quotes, this example works!)

So, I started making the `arg` more and more explicit, by adding all the special characters that I want to be parsed like so:

```
arg = pp.quotedString | pp.Word(pp.alphanums + ' \'[].:=&!*#$/+') | fnc
```

The problem now is that the function recursion breaks when I do this. The example `"&foo('$arg1', &foo(arg2))"` throws an exception `expecting ")" (at char 18)` (right after the inner `foo`). Including the parentheses in the symbols above will finally get to the end of the string but it always breaks at the last position expecting ")" again.

I tried to counter this by using `pp.printables` and excluding the parentheses like this:

```
arg = pp.quotedString | pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars="()") | fnc
```

But this yields similar results.
Thus my question. Is there anything (a regex type or something else) like `quotedString` that works out of the box but for unquoted strings? I thank you in advance for any pointers/solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23332492/21376777) to the referenced question you would probably list the grammar's elements explicitly to enable nested function calls.  For example, the following lists functions, keywords and literals as possible function arguments.

```py
import pyparsing as pp

test_str1 = "&foo(1,2.5,3.635, mode='multiply', decimals=3)"
test_str2 = "&foo('$arg1', &foo(arg2))"

fnc = pp.Forward()

literal = pp.quotedString | pp.common.number | pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
kw = literal + '=' + literal
arg = fnc | kw | literal

fnc <<= pp.Group(pp.Word('!$#&')
                 + pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
                 + '('
                 + pp.Optional(pp.delimitedList(arg))
                 + ')'
)

print(list(fnc.scanString(test_str1)))
print(list(fnc.scanString(test_str2)))
```

This gives

```
[(ParseResults([ParseResults(['&', 'foo', '(', 1, 2.5, 3.635, 'mode', '=', "'multiply'", 'decimals', '=', 3, ')'], {})], {}), 0, 46)]
[(ParseResults([ParseResults(['&', 'foo', '(', "'$arg1'", ParseResults(['&', 'foo', '(', 'arg2', ')'], {}), ')'], {})], {}), 0, 25)]
```